# SwiftUI: Toolbar that covers bottom safeArea

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to implement a bottom toolbar that covers the bottom safeArea so that my bannerView can sit nicely above the toolbar without having my listView content peeking through. In UIKit, I can easily implement this by creating a `UIToolbar` and set the top and bottom anchors to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` and `view.bottomAnchor`.

How do I implement the same for SwiftUI?

Current SwiftUI implementation:

```
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach (0..<30) { i in
                        Text("Row \(i)")
                    }
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(height: 50)
                    //Toolbar??
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .toolbar {
                //Setting empty toolbar doesn't work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UIKit equivalent implementation:

```
let toolbar: UIToolbar = {
    let tb = UIToolbar()
    tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tb
}()

let bannerView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    return v
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
    view.addSubview(toolbar)
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

SwiftUI results:

[image]

Desired results:

[image]

Comment: Add a ToolbarItemGroup in the toolbar then, it will give you the desired look.

Comment: Try to add ```.clipped()``` to ZStack

Comment: Or you can try this ```   .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Color.white
                }
            }```

Comment: @RajaKishan Tried both .clipped() and Toolbar. Both doesn't really achieve what I want. clipped() offsets the entire list upwards such that the first row gets obscured, and ToolbarItem simply adds an entire toolbar/tabbar which is not what I want.

Comment: @RTXGamer tried ToolbarItemGroup as well, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks after adding `ToolbarItemGroup` in the toolbar and bottom padding to the list:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var date: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
               ZStack {
                   List {
                       ForEach (0..<30) { i in
                           Text("Row \(i)")
                       }
                   }.padding(.bottom, 20)
                   
                   VStack {
                       Spacer()
                       Rectangle()
                           .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                           .frame(height: 50)
                       //Toolbar??
                   }
               }
               .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
               .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
               .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {}
               }
           }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn’t possible.

SwiftUI will show toolbar only if there is the item in it. Strictly speaking that is the proper behavior, the toolbar is meant for showing items, not for creating a background for something.

So you will have to use some alternative. I don’t see why you wouldn’t be able to use just a white rectangle that goes into the safe area but I don’t know the rest of your app and I assume that there is some reason for that.